# Regex for email validation in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this regular expression for email validation:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

But this is not working for emails like:

```
test+1@gmail.com
```

How do I change the above regular expression for this requirement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: surely there must be many examples of email validation regex all over S.O.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` was not icluded in your regex pattern. I have added that. Hope this works.

`^\w+([\.\-\+]?\w*)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$`

Comment: @pranami. Thank you for approving the answer. Happy to have an upvote aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add RegEx for the '+' symbol

```
^\w+([\.+-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$
```